# Finding a linear regression prediction with keras

Tags: keras, linear-regression, predict

I trained a linear regression model (a CNN with a linear regression output). My inputs are images and the output are probabilities. I now want to take another image (different to my test set) and push it through my network to get a probability.

I load my model, weights and the image and reshape to be a 4D tensor and run prediction like so:

```
json_file = open('/home/model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("/home/weights.h5")
loaded_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=OPTIMISER, metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

img = (ndimage.imread(img).astype(float) - pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth
img = img.reshape(1, 128, 128, 1).astype('float32')
out = loaded_model.predict(img)
```

I get a value of 7.35 - but my network has been performing on the test set in the region of 0.4 (which is fine for what I need). I was expecting a value of ~1. Am I using the right routine?

Not sure how far to go back looking for the bug.

EDIT: histogram plots of images.

[image: Training set images hist]
[image: Test set images hist]

Comment: Have you normalized your images while training?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Yes

Comment: And while prediction - have you normalized it using the same function?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Yes.

Comment: Can you plot histograms of flattened examples from both test and training sets?

Comment: Of the images themselves? I can probably plot a histogram but I am wondering of what - I previously looked at the different distributions training and test and they are similar - ie I have a representation of training in my test data.

Comment: No - I just want to check if distributions of pixel values in both training and test are the same. So - Flatten images to vectors and plot their histograms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158006/discussion-between-ashley-and-marcin-mozejko).

Comment: @MarcinMożejko pls see updated with histograms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I am getting exactly what I need. The prediction is based on a shift in orientation which the network is picking up as being made possible because of an obstruction that is now not an issue (a physical obstruction in the 3D environment). At first, I thought I was trying to find a similar value of prediction, but this turns out to be better.

Learning: The way this is structured is correct for finding a linear prediction using keras.